# Python/Pandas: How to make a list of column values based on the row name (pattern) chosen?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gl8Wz.png)How do I implement based on the pattern name a list of values for it - see image

Say I choose "Pattern_8_0_100_8_2" I want the values (8, 0, 100, 8, 2) in the columns associated with that row to be a list. Is there a way to achieve this in pandas library?

Lists I want to create:

`Pattern_8_0_100_8_2 = ['8', '0', '100', '8', '2']`

`Pattern_8_0_200_16_3 = ['8', '0', '200', '16', '3']`

`Pattern_8_0_300_32_4 = ['8', '0', '300', '32', '4']`

`Pattern_8_0_400_64_5 = ['8', '0', '400', '64', '5']`

So far I am able to read the xlxs file that contains my data and print the data in terms of a specific row (see image)

`import pandas as pd`

`dyn_power_df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\power.xlsx")`

`dyn_power_df[dyn_power_df["pattern"] == "Pattern_8_0_100_8_2"]`

I imagine we have to use a conditional (if-else) statement based on  the pattern name to store the values in the columns associated with it? Is there an easier way? Please help as I'm still new to python/pandas. Thanks!

Comment: you can split the columns the by `_`. You need to provide a minimal example

Comment: I'm not trying to split the numerals in my pattern name but add values in the column associated with the row/pattern name, in a list.

Answer (score 1):

First let's build an empty DataFrame.

```
patterns = [
    "Pattern_8_0_100_8_2",
    "Pattern_8_0_200_16_3",
    "Pattern_8_0_300_32_4",
    "Pattern_8_0_400_64_5",
]

columns = [
    "Channel Count",
    "FEC count",
    "Input Clock Freq",
    "Data Rate",
    "Post PLL Divider",
]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=patterns)
```

Now we can iterate through the DataFrame, and split the index into columns.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    li = index.split("_")
    for c in range(5):
        df.loc[index][c] = int(li[c + 1])
```

Finally, we can zip the index with the columns from the DataFrame just created to create a list of tuples that have your pattern and then the list of values.

```
print(list(zip(df.index, df.values.tolist())))
```

The resulting output is:

```
[('Pattern_8_0_100_8_2', [8, 0, 100, 8, 2]),
 ('Pattern_8_0_200_16_3', [8, 0, 200, 16, 3]),
 ('Pattern_8_0_300_32_4', [8, 0, 300, 32, 4]),
 ('Pattern_8_0_400_64_5', [8, 0, 400, 64, 5])]
```